# How do you concatenate multi-byte LPSTR string?

Tags: c, concatenation

I am working on a small GUI calculator project and I ran into a problem when I executed the following code:

```
HWND edit = GetDlgItem(hWnd, BUTTON_ZERO);
LPSTR currText = "";
GetDlgItemText(hWnd, EDIT_NUMBER, currText, INT_MAX);
LPSTR num = "0";
LPSTR newText = "";
StringCchCopy(newText, INT_MAX, currText);
StringCchCat(newText, INT_MAX, num);
SendMessage(editNumber, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, LPARAM(LPCSTR(newText)));
```

I am trying to concatenate `currText` and `num` into `newText`.
When I execute this code, it gives me an error:

```
0xC000041D: An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared newText as a pointer to the constant text "", which cannot be written.

Try CHAR newText[256] instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I press the button again, the text gets appended not added: for example, if I press zero, it shows 0. If I press it again, it shows just 0 instead of 00. How can I make it show 00?

Comment: Same issue with currText, which should be declared as CHAR currText[256]. Windows is just clever enough to check an invalid pointer, avoiding the crash. If you checked the return value of GetDlgItemText, it would returned FALSE.

Comment: thanks - that worked. another question i had was how can i limit the number of characters a user can input so that they don't input more than 256 characters?